# HTML table row height for single cell width

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a table which can have a variable number of rows, and every row has 1 cell width.

However, in some cases, I want a row to have the height of several rows (say 3 rows for example). I have tried playing with rowspan for this, however it seems to wrap the preceding rows into the same row (not what I want).

Is there a way to do with for a single cell width table?

Edit: example added

```
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td height="3">big</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>small</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: rowspan has no meaning if there is only a single column in the table. Try height instead.

Comment: I solved this by avoiding it all togehter. I added some new rows (containing nothing but a space), and removed the top/bottom borders making it appear to be 1 large cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With single column its impossible to go for rowspan. if you are trying for multiple lines within a cell use `<br/>`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using CSS instead.

```
 <style>
     .big{
         height:100px;
     }

     .small{
        height:30px;
     }
 </style>



<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="big">big</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">small</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="small">small</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```